# How to utilize re-usable Razor component/view/page (Razor Class Library and ASP.NET Core 6 MVC) through plain html and Javascript?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I are trying to develop a shareable widget.

I am developing by using razor.view, razor.page and razor.component (project templates are  Razor Class Library and ASP.NET Core 6 MVC).

[image]

`_Imports.razor` under RCL Project is as follows:

```
 @using System.Net.Http  
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization  
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization  
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms  
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing  
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web  
 @using Microsoft.JSInterop   
 @using System.IO  
 @using CarRentalWidget.Models.DBEntities.Franchises
 @using CarRentalWidget.Models.ViewModels.GooogleGeoCodes
```

`AutoCompleteLocationsComponent.razor` is as follows:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@inject HttpClient Http
@namespace CarRentalWidget.RCL.CarWidgetUI.Pages
<div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="TxtBxPickUpLoc"
                    class="postcode tf-form-control"
                    placeholder="Please Enter Postcode or Town"                                      
                   value="@inputValue"
                   @onchange="DoChangeLocation"
                    autoComplete="off"
                />
                            @if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputValue))
                            {
                                <a className="location" href="#" id="branch-selector" onClick={onClearLocations}></a>
                            }
                            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputValue))
                            {
                                <a className="location empty" href="#" id="branch-selector" onClick={onClearLocations}></a>
                            }
                 
        </div>
        <div class="sautocomplete-content-container tk-search-drop-wrapper ac-drop-active">
            <div class="sautocomplete-content tk-search-drop">
                <div class="branch-info">                          
                    <ul id="LocationSuggestions" class="suggestions">
                @if (locationData != null && locationData.Count() > 0)
                {
                    @foreach (FranchiseWebInquiry suggestion in locationData!)
                    {
                        // Flag the active suggestion with a class
                        if (index == activeSuggestionIndex)
                        {
                            className = "suggestion-active";
                        }
                        <li class="@className" key="@index + @suggestion.FranchiseName" onClick="onClick(suggestion)">
                            <a pickupid="@suggestion.PickupId + @suggestion.FranchisesId"  franchisesid="@suggestion.FranchisesId" subofficeid="@suggestion.SubOfficeId" href="#">
                                <span class="locName">@suggestion.FranchiseName</span>
                                <span class="locDetails">@getAddress(suggestion)                                            
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        ++index;
                    }
                }
            </ul>                              
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
  
@code {
    private string inputValue = "";
    private string className = "";
    private int activeSuggestionIndex;
    private int index = 0;  
    private FranchiseWebInquiry[]? locationData;
    private bool getError;
    private bool shouldRender;

    protected override bool ShouldRender() => shouldRender;
    private GoogleGeocode? currentMapItems;  

    private async Task<GoogleGeocode?> loadGoogleGeoCodeData(string postCodeOrTown)
    {
        currentMapItems = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GoogleGeocode?>
        ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?types=geocode&language=en&key=mykey&address=" + postCodeOrTown);
        return currentMapItems;
    }

    private async Task getLocationsApi(string postCodeOrTown)
    {
        await loadGoogleGeoCodeData(postCodeOrTown);
        Result? serviceResult = currentMapItems!.Results!.FirstOrDefault();
        Location? locDetail = serviceResult != null && serviceResult.Geometry != null ? serviceResult.Geometry.Location:null;
        double providedLattitude = locDetail != null ? locDetail.Lat : 0;
        double providedLongitude = locDetail != null ? locDetail.Lng : 0;
        locationData = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<FranchiseWebInquiry[]?>
        ("https://localhost:7177/api/CarRental/allfranchises/?postCodeOrAddress=" + postCodeOrTown + "&lattitude=" + providedLattitude + "&longitude=" + providedLongitude);
    }

    private async void DoChangeLocation(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        inputValue = e.Value!.ToString();
        if (inputValue!.Length >= 5)
        {
           await getLocationsApi(inputValue);         
        }
        Console.WriteLine("It is definitely: " + inputValue);
    }    

    private string getAddress(FranchiseWebInquiry suggestion)
    {
        //debugger;
       string localAddress = "";

       if (suggestion != null)
       {
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suggestion.Address1))
          {
                localAddress =  suggestion.Address1 + " , ";
           }                  

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suggestion.Address2))
           {
                localAddress += suggestion.Address2 + " , ";
           }

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suggestion.Address3))
           {
                localAddress += suggestion.Address3 + " , ";
           } 

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suggestion.Town))
           {
                localAddress += suggestion.Town + "- " + (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suggestion.PostCode) ? "(" + suggestion.PostCode + "), ":"");
           }

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suggestion.PrimaryContact))
           {
                localAddress += suggestion.PrimaryContact;
           }           
        }

        return localAddress;  
    }   
}
```

and `Index.cshtml` is as follows:

```
@page "/car-index"
@model CarRentalWidget.RCL.CarWidgetUI.Pages.IndexPageModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Car Rental Widget</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="widget-wrapper">
            <div class="main-heading">
                <h1>               
                    Test 1
                </h1>                 
            </div>
            <div class="widget-slider">
                <div class="row step-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="pickup-location tf-search-group">
                            <div class="label-location tf-search-label">pick up location</div>
                            <div id="PickUpLocationControlId" class="input-group-location tf-search-field">                                                                               
                                <div class="card">   
                                @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<CarRentalWidget.RCL.CarWidgetUI.Pages.AutoCompleteLocationsComponent>
                                    (RenderMode.ServerPrerendered/*,new {  Data="I came from Index",style= "badge-danger" }*/))  
                                 </div>                               
                            </div>                                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I just added the reference in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project and open the browser and tried this url in the browser.

```
https://localhost:7177/car-index
```

Everything is working as expected. No issue till so far.
[image]

Now I am trying to consume this through a plain html (and Javascript/jQuery).

My client end application request is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "https://localhost:7177/car-index", success: function(result){
      $("#CarWidget").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="CarWidget">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See I tried with above script, there is no error code even in Browser Network tab.

Why?

[image]

For detailed understanding, you can follow this link  as well

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/comments/872715/view.html
```

and these links

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio
```

Comment: You should understand that Blazor's UI is not rendered via HTML but rather by directly manipulating the DOM.  Your line `$("#CarWidget").html(result)` is just going to give you the scaffolding HTML but will not include your actual UI as that is dynamically generated.  You could try using an IFRAME, but this approach of trying to just grab the HTML out of an AJAX request will be a complete non-starter.

Comment: it is possible to write a Razor Class Library and then Add a reference in Asp.Net MVC Core 6 Application with some configurations.
This is not a pure blazor project/application rather it is considered to be a Razor project.

And I thought that I can invoke through JavaScript As We work through Razor Views and can use DOM through JavaScript/JQuery.
My problem was to share a widget through a public Url and my client application can use it like I mentioned above (in plain html and JavaScript)